# 'module' object is not callable typeerror django

Tags: python, django

So I have a module that I successfully use. But now I added another file to module and it gives me this error.

I have a file `generate_bags_uk` that has method:

```
def generate_bags(bags, price):
```

And I use it like this:

```
from excelgenerator import generate_bags_uk
...
uk_bag = generate_bags_uk.generate_bags(tshirts, form.cleaned_data['price_uk_bag'])
```

And I get TypeError: module is not callable. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code instead -

```
from excelgenerator.generate_bags_uk import generate_bags
...
uk_bag = generate_bags(tshirts, form.cleaned_data['price_uk_bag'])
```

and make sure `excelgenerator` folder has a `__init__.py` inside  it, otherwise it will not be dealt as a python package.

Also, I guess the method has a body, if it does not then at least give it a definition -

```
def generate_bags(bags, price):
    pass
```

**COMMENT** : From the looks of this error, the error is happening in file `/home/marijus/workspace/tshirtnation/excelgenerator/generate_bags_uk.py`. I think your other calls are also of similar format and thus causing error. Please change them as I mentioned. The problem should be solved.

Comment: I use other files from namespace exactly like I try to use generate_bags_uk file. And folder does have init inside of it.

Comment: do they have the same name or different name?

Comment: I just tried your solution. The exact same error. And the method does have body.

Comment: What do you mean other calls are of similiar format ? How can it cause error ? I tried your suggested solution but it didn't work. Also I tried adding another method to my generate uk bags file and that method works fine. This is really really strange :/

Comment: Then the problem is probably inside the function, have you tried checking the code of the function? since the other function is just working fine from that same file.